# django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: news/index.html

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

[image: Структура кода]

**news/views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Bd


# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    bbs = Bd.objects.all()
    return render(request, template_name='news/index.html', context={'bbs': bbs})
```

**news/settings.py:**

```
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-u=qw39)^uec+r=^xsnr+9ygi*h%bo-+x@$=spxl^q3i28q4j_!'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'border'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'news.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'news.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> Нзавание сайта </title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Объявление</h1>
    {% for bb in bbs %}
        <div>
            <h2>{{ bb.title}}</h2>
            <p>{{bb.price}}</p>
        </div>
    {% enffor %}
</body>
</html>
```

**border/models.py:**

```
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class Bd(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(max_length=20)
    price = models.IntegerField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Объявления'
        verbose_name = 'Объявление'
        ordering = ['-price', ]
```

**border/views.py**

```
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class Bd(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(max_length=20)
    price = models.IntegerField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Объявления'
        verbose_name = 'Объявление'
        ordering = ['-price', ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Папка templates должна находиться внутри созданного приложения, в твоем случае под папкой border.

Comment: news  - это встроенная папка, которая создается при создании проекта.

Comment: А, я не там шаблоны поместил, спасибо.

Comment: точно, а шаблоны надо было поместить в border app. Я отредактировал мой ответ

Comment: можно news в INSTALLED_APPS поместить, тоже будет работать

Answer (score 0):

Исправьте `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],`
с

```
    TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

на:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

Answer (score 0):

Раз у Вас шаблон находится в папке проекта, то есть 2 варианта

1. Переместить папку `templates` из папки проекта (`news/news`) на уровень выше и следовать ответу @Fedor
2. Указать в `TEMPLATES` верную папку

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'news', 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    ....
}
```